# SimpleXML php format

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

Working on creating an xml file from an array. As part of the data is a string of the structure of where the value should exist. It is formatted as a string something like 'path/to/field'. I explode that by the delimiter and loop through each piece to create the xml. It all looks good but not the format I want. The code looks like:

```
foreach ($path_parts as $path_part) {
    if($path_count == $path_parts_count) {
        $path_item->addChild($path_part, $field['value']);
    } else {
        $path_item = $path_item->addChild($path_part);
    }
    $path_count++;
}
```

The xml looks like this:

```
<path>
    <to>
        <field>value 1</field>
    </to>
</path>
<path>
    <to>
        <field>value 2</field>
    </to>
</path>
```

What I am trying to do is make it look like the following:

```
<path>
    <to>
        <field>value 1</field>
        <field>value 2</field>
    </to>
</path>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I need to see `$path_parts` to understand the issue.

Comment: @michi I explode the path so is an array of the path for that value. In this simple case it is the array that looks like array('path', 'to', 'field').

Comment: I see.You need to check the XML if a given path is already existing. What is the exact format of that array before you process it?

Comment: here's what I've been playing around with, won't set field values though https://eval.in/496723